# The Geodesics of a Sphere.

Tags: calculus

I need to find the geodesics of a sphere. Then in polar coordinates
$$x=a \sin\theta \cos\phi \\y=a \sin\theta \sin\phi\\  
z=a\cos\theta$$

Then $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$.
Can someone please tell me how is $ds^2=a^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta \, d\phi ^2)$ obtained. I don't know much about spherical coordinates.

Comment: Do you know how to write, for example, $dx$ in terms of $\theta,\phi,d\theta,$ and $d\phi$?

Comment: @user153841 No I don't know how to write $dx$

Comment: This is sometimes called the "total derivative" of $x$: $dx=\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} \, d\theta + \frac{\partial x}{\partial\phi} \, d\phi$. Try computing that, as well as the corresponding terms for $y$ and $z$.

Comment: @user153841 Thanks a lot.I was able to compute it

Comment: @user153841 -- No problem. When you have computed $dy$ and $dz$ and add up $dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$, there should be some sign cancellation and trig identities taking you to $ds^2=a^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta d\phi^2)$. Do you know how to tackle the geodesic part of the question?

Comment: @user153841 Haven't gone to the rest of the problem.Was stuck here.Have to try to do the geodesic part

Comment: @user153841 In calculating the geodesic part I came upto        $\phi prime= {k\over sin\theta\sqrt{sin^2\theta-k^2}}$.Can you please tell me so far whether I have done correctly.And if so  how to compute this integral

Comment: That's correct so far. The $\sin \theta$ in the denominator is probably irking you, right? Try moving it to the numerator then play around with recasting in terms of $\csc \theta$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than discuss via comments, here's an explicit list of steps/hints. Perhaps you can look at them only when stuck:

**Step 1.** Admittedly, the integral you mentioned is not easy. Here's one approach:
\begin{align*}
\phi &= \int \frac{k \, d\theta}{\sin \theta \sqrt{ \sin^2 \theta-k^2}} 
= \int\frac{k \, d \theta}{\sin^2\theta\sqrt{1-k^2\csc^2\theta}}
= \int\frac{k \csc^2 \theta \, d \theta}{\sqrt{1-k^2(1+\cot^2 \theta)}}.
\end{align*}
Now use a $u$-sub.

**Step 2.** Setting $u=\cot \theta$, we have $du=d(\cot \theta)=-\csc^2 \theta \, d\theta$, hence
\begin{align*}
\phi &= \int \frac{-k \, du}{\sqrt{1-k^2(1+u^2)}} = -\int \frac{ \, du}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1-k^2}{k^2}\right) -u^2}}.
\end{align*}
**Step 3.** Using the formula $\int (a^2-x^2)^{-1/2} \, dx = \sin^{-1}(x/a)$, we have
\begin{align*}
\phi= - \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{(1-k^2)/k^2}}\right)+C= -\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{k \cot \theta}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}\right)+C.
\end{align*}

**Step 4.** Compose with sine and use sum/difference formulas: $$k \cot \theta / \sqrt{1-k^2} = \sin(C-\phi)=\sin(C)\cos(\phi)-\cos(C)\sin(\phi).$$ 
Multiplying by $\sin \theta$, this gives
$$ k \cos \theta /\sqrt{1-k^2} = \sin (C) \cos (\phi) \sin (\theta)-\cos (C)\sin(\phi) \sin(\theta).$$

**Step 5.** Switch back to Cartesian coordinates:
$$\frac{k}{ \sqrt{1-k^2}}\cdot \frac{z}{a} = \sin(C) \cdot \frac{x}{a} - \cos(C) \cdot \frac{y}{a}.$$
Note that $k$ and $C$ are constants, so this is a linear relation of $x$, $y$, and $z$. What set of points satisfies such a relation? When you intersect the sphere with this set, you get a geodesic.

Comment: Thanks a lot.That integration part is a lot difficult.I wouldn't be able to think of it myself

Comment: Suppose I need to find the geodesic on a sphere but cartesian coordinates using euler lagrange eqyation then is the following correct - in the expression for ds^2 I will evaluate d(theta) and d(phi) in terms of dx dy dz and then use the equation of sphere to eliminate 1 of dx dy dz, say dz... And then use that ds in terms of dx dy and I should get the cartesian equation of a circle... Is that right... I just want to know this.... The only problem is what will be the limits of the integral

Answer (score 4):

Well from

$\begin{eqnarray}
x &=& r \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi)\\
y &=& r \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi)\\
z &=& r \cos(\theta)\\
\end{eqnarray}$

follows

$\begin{eqnarray}
dx &=& \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi) dr + r \cos(\theta) \cos(\phi) d\theta - r \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi) d\phi\\
dy &=& \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi) dr + r \cos(\theta) \sin(\phi) d\theta + r \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi) d\phi\\
dz &=& \cos(\theta) dr - r \sin(\theta) d\theta\\
\end{eqnarray}$

and for the surface we have $dr=0$, thus

$\begin{eqnarray}
dx &=& r \cos(\theta) \cos(\phi) d\theta - r \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi) d\phi\\
dy &=& r \cos(\theta) \sin(\phi) d\theta + r \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi) d\phi\\
dz &=& r \sin(\theta) d\theta\\
\end{eqnarray}$

Then we find that

$\begin{eqnarray}
dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 &=& \Big( r \cos(\theta) \cos(\phi) d\theta - r \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi) d\phi \Big)^2\\
&& + \Big( r \cos(\theta) \sin(\phi) d\theta + r \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi) d\phi \Big)^2\\
&& + \Big( r \sin(\theta) d\theta \Big)^2\\
&=& r^2 \Big( \cos^2(\theta) \cos^2(\phi) d\theta^2 - 2 \cos(\theta) \cos(\phi) \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi) d\theta d\phi\\
&&\hspace{2em} + \sin^2(\theta) \sin^2(\phi) d\phi^2\\
&& + \cos^2(\theta) \sin^2(\phi) d\theta^2 - 2 \cos(\theta) \sin(\phi) \sin(\theta) \cos(\phi) d\theta d\phi\\
&&\hspace{2em} + \sin^2(\theta) \cos^2(\phi) d\phi^2\\
&& + \sin^2(\theta) d\theta^2
\Big)
\end{eqnarray}$
$\begin{eqnarray}
dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 &=& r^2 \Big( d\theta^2 + \sin^2(\theta) d\phi^2 \Big)
\end{eqnarray}$

Comment: Suppose I need to find the geodesic on a sphere but cartesian coordinates using euler lagrange eqyation then is the following correct - in the expression for ds^2 I will evaluate d(theta) and d(phi) in terms of dx dy dz and then use the equation of sphere to eliminate 1 of dx dy dz, say dz... And then use that ds in terms of dx dy and I should get the cartesian equation of a circle... Is that right... I just want to know this.... The only problem is what will be the limits of the integral